# Документация по yii2

Tags: yii2

допустим есть у менять input в yii2

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'requisitesData['.$requisite->requisite_id.']['.$requisite->id.'][value]')->textInput(['value' => $requisite->value])->label(false) ?>
```

допустим есть у меня задача добавить этому инпуту readonly

Помогите разобраться с тем, где искать информацию по yii2 которая касается метода textInput и того, как в него синтаксически правильно втыкнуть мой readonly

Есть этот [сайт](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/helper-html/) и [этот](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#textInput()-detail)  но там максимум описывается то, что есть такой метод как textInput, а какие аттрибуты могут быть у него, в котором мог бы быть мой readonly - такого списка нет. Описывается так:

```
public $this textInput ( $options = [] )
```

а вот что можно втыкнуть в этот $options = [] и как синтаксически правильно это сделать - нет информации

Когда я начинал изучать пхп, то http://php.net/ хватало по завязку, всё подробно написано, но как люди пишут на yii2 я не понимаю. но как-то ж пишут. Прошу понять правильно. Мне нужна помощь не в том, как правильно написать, а в том где и как найти нужную мне инфу в частности на примере с этим readonly.

Спасибо.

Comment: я дополнил ответ. чтобы комментировать ответ нажмите кнопку `добавить комментарий` под ответом. источник информации - 3 ваши ссылки. пользуйтесь.

Comment: Это особенность yii2-подхода к разработке. Там много где параметры массивом задаются. Как вариант, можно пройтись поиском и найти способы использования. Хоть в том же вендоре.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'readonly' => true]) ?>
```

все прекрасно работает:

```
<input type="text" id="products-name" class="form-control" name="Products[name]" readonly="" aria-required="true">
```

в массиве `options` перечисляете необходимые атрибуты и их значения.

так же можно добавлять и пользовательские аттрибуты:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'newAttr' => Yii::$app->user->identity->last_ip ]) ?>
```

выглядит так:

```
<input type="text" id="products-name" class="form-control" name="Products[name]" newattr="127.0.0.1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

> Мне нужна помощь не в том, как правильно написать, а в том где и как
>   найти нужную мне инфу в частности на примере с этим readonly.

вы уже нашли 2 документации: оригинал и перевод. большего и не нужно.

пробуйте, не сломаете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но меня интересует не синтаксис, а источник информации.

Comment: @Oughtem, вы уже нашли документацию. какого рода источник информации вы хотите найти, если документации вам не хватает? в том же переводе про массив $options черным по белому написано: `Третий аргумент - это массив настроек для HTML-кода, а другими словами - массив атрибутов для тэга. В этом массиве ключи являются названиями атрибутов, например class, href или target, а значения в массиве являются значениями этих атрибутов.`